# R - Delete a library path to keep the default one

Tags: r, libraries

I don't know when this happened, but I used to have only one library path where I installed my packages. But now it appears I have 2 of them and I want to get rid of the new one, since all packages I install go directly to that new library.

```
.libPaths()
[1] "/Users/myusername/Library/R/3.3/library"                         
[2] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library"
```

I want to get rid of path [1] and keep the other one. Or at least move path [2] to the default spot.

Btw, I'm running on Mac OSX 10.11.6

Comment: The user library is added when using `install.packages` for the first time as an user. It has precedence over the system's.

Comment: @RicardoCruz but this happened sometime after I installed R in this machine. 90% of my packages are in the system's.

Comment: @RicardoCruz means that, after you installed R originally, you probably followed instructions to install an optional package. This is done using the `install.packages` command from *inside* R.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get it.